# ボタンの中に斜めの線を入れたい

Tags: html, css

HTML, CSS初心者です。
添付の画像のように、斜め線が入ったボタンの実装をしようと思い、
実装サンプル集を参考に色々試行錯誤しましたが、斜め線をボタンの中に組み込む実装がうまくできませんでした。
cssサンプルをご提示いただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: button-sample.png]

Comment: 参照している "実装サンプル集" についての情報や、うまく行かない状態でも構わないので実際に試したコードを質問中に含めておくと回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: 斜め線とひとことで言っても案外種類あります。右斜め・左斜め, 何を望むか。対角じゃなさそうだけど線の位置指定か画像のように固定か。画像背景なら色も固定のはずだけど変化させるかどうか。あとアスペクト比によって線の太さ変わってもいいのか … など。(判る範囲で)。そんなにいっぺんに条件出せないかもだけど, 回答側もサンプル出したのに「コレジャナイ」扱いは嫌でしょうし

Answer (score 0):

cssで実現できる方法もあるかもしれませんが、思いつくのは、ボタンに画像を貼り付けることは出来ると思います。

Answer (score 0):

ボタンに貼り付ける画像の生成と, あとは CSS辺りに `background-image: url("./img/bg.png");` などと指定するとできるはず。
ただし実行する環境によっては指定するパスが異なるかも。

(colab, VS Code で確認)

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw 

def imdraw(sz=128):
    img = Image.new("RGB", (sz, sz))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.rectangle([0, 0, sz, sz], fill='LightBlue')
    for n in range(0, 80, 20):
        draw.line((60 +n, 0, n, sz), fill='Orange', width=6)
    img.putalpha(204)   # 透過率
    return img

with open('./img/bg.png', 'wb') as fp:
    imdraw(100).save(fp)

from IPython.display import Image
display(Image('./img/bg.png'))
```

---

ほかに border使ったもの。線というか, 境界線だけど。

(そのほかにも各種各様の方法があり, きりがないのでカット)

```css
.border {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    border-bottom: 2rem solid LightSalmon;
    border-left: 6rem solid transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 0;
    width: 12rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
<button class="border">border</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

input type="image" を使うのも一つの方法です。

```html
<input type="image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
```

Answer (score 0):

目的を3色のストライプと考えます。

- 1色目と3色目: 同じ色であり、背景となる
- 2色目: 描きたい線

CSSでストライプを実現するため、[linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient) を使います。

```css
button {
  color: black;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  
  /* ストライプ */
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, aliceblue 1.5em, orange 0 2.2em, aliceblue 0 100%);
  
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0.25em 3em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<button>button-sample</button>
```